# an array of integers,the first part of the array consists of odd numbers in ascending order and the second part even numbers in descending order

Tags: arrays, sorting

Given an array of integers, sort this array so the first part of the array consists of odd numbers in ascending order and the second part of the array consists of even numbers in descending order
For example, 
input: 5,3,6,8,1,7,2
output: 1,3,5,7,8,6,2

Thanks in advance!(JAVA)

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place to ask people to do your homework.

Comment: You don't even tell about the language you are using. If you want to use Python, remember that the sorting functions accept a key as a parameter for sorting things according arbitrary kinds of order.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in `O(nlogn)`. First sort the whole array with any of sorting algorithm you prefer in `O(nlogn)`.

So you get `1 2 3 5 6 7 8`.

Make a new array. Then make one pass through the array beginning from first element. If it is odd place it in the beginning of the array, if it is even then place it in the end:

```
int i = 0, j = n - 1;

for(int k = 0; k < n; k++)
{
    if(oldarray[k] % 2 == 1)
       newarray[i++] = oldarray[k];
    else
       newarray[j--] = oldarray[k];
}
```